# How to make a drawn rectangle name come from a variable

Tags: vb.net, draw, rectangles

I know how to make buttons with a variable name like so:

```
Dim newbuttonname As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim createdButton = New Button()
createdButton.Name = newbuttonname
'...
```

In a similar way, I want to name my own rectangle from a variable:

```
Dim variablename As New Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 200)
g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, rect:=variablename)
```

I want `rect:=` to be dynamic so I can use the same code to build lots of uniquely named variables but of course here it only has the name "variablename".

Comment: You could always create a new object, say, `MyRectangle` which simply inherits `Rectangle` and then give it a `name` property